# Is there an equivalent book/resource to "The Linux Programming Interface" for FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, programming, interface, books

Most of you here are probably aware of the famous *The Linux Programming Interface*, which presents a truly masterful guide to the Linux and general POSIX APIs. I know that much of the general POSIX knowledge can be applied to all Unix/Unix-like systems.

However, I'm interested as to whether there is an equivalent book, document or resource concerning lower level FreeBSD systems programming and interfaces that are exclusive to it, such as GEOM and devd. Or should I simply stick to manpages and docs?

Answer (score 5):

There is "The Design and Implementation of FreeBSD"

2004 Edition: http://smile.amazon.com/Design-Implementation-FreeBSD-Operating-System/dp/0201702452/

2014 Edition (will be released in September): http://smile.amazon.com/Design-Implementation-FreeBSD-Operating-Edition/dp/0321968972/

The classic 1996 edition is also available for free on the FreeBSD website: http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/design-44bsd/

If you are into history, there is also a 1989 edition: "The Design and Implementation of the 4.3 BSD UNIX Operating System"

Answer (score 1):

There are some official documentation available from FreeBSD:

- [FreeBSD Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/): which is more about the system and its administration
- [FreeBSD Developer's Handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/developers-handbook/): a more recent addition targeting system development

I think you would find some answers in the later, but development mailing list and forum are still a way to get information as all might not be there.

A good starting point is the official [FreeBSD developer web page](http://www.freebsd.org/projects/index.html): gathering all things related to the system development, whether it is ports related or deep kernel hacks.